# How do I find ID in an Array List of student objects

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public class Student { //student object class containing name and id
    String name;
    int ID;

    public Student(String name, int ID) {
        this.name = name;
        this.ID = ID;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name +" "+ ID;
    }
}
//another class with two array lists, an array of students in a class and an array of students waiting for help
ArrayList<Student> inClass = new ArrayList<Student>();
ArrayList<Integer> inLine = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //IDs of students who are waiting for help

public boolean addStudentInLine(Integer id) { 
   for(int i = 0; i<inClass.size(); i++) {
      if (inClass.get(i).ID != id) {
          return false;
      }
      if (inClass.get(i).ID == id) {
          inClass.add(id);
      }
  }  
}
```

For the addStudentInLine method, I need to add the id to the integer Arraylist inLine if the id exists in inClass arraylist.(only students in a class can receive help) If the id does not exist in inClass arrayList, return false. I'm not sure how to traverse through the inClass arrayList in order to see if the id already exist because inClass arrayList consists of student objects. I've tried .contain() method but it also seems to not work. can someone please help?

Comment: You won't know for sure if the user exists in the list or not until you've traversed the entire list, so you're preemptive exit (with `false`) isn't going to work.  However, if you do find the student, you can exist early, as there's no need to continue checking the list.  I would remove the `if (inClass.get(i).ID != id) {...}`, add a `return true`; to the `if (inClass.get(i).ID == id) {...}` block and add a default `return false;` to the end of the method

Comment: Just a side note... the `Integer == Integer` comparisons will probably raise other questions. Maybe you should declare `id` as `int` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reverse the condition in `addStudentInLine`  method, If any `Student` id matching to `ID` add that `ID` to `inLine` list and return `true` or else just return `false

```
public boolean addStudentInLine(Integer id) { 

   for(int i = 0; i<inClass.size(); i++) {

       if (inClass.get(i).ID.equals(id)) {
           inClass.add(id);
           return true;
        }

     }  
    return false;
 }
```

You can also use `for-each` block

```
 public boolean addStudentInLine(Integer id) { 

   for(Student stu : inClass) {

       if (stu.ID.equals(id)) {
           inClass.add(id);
           return true;
        }

     }  
    return false;
 }
```